# Jarsigner showing error for the file which is not exist

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, jarsigner

I have created ionic app and followed all of the things as below

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

`jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.jks platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk alias_name`

`zipalign -v 4 platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\IMDB.apk`

When I am going to upload IMDB.apk to google play it is showing me this error

`You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK or Android App Bundle.`

I have tried this to resolve it

`jarsigner -verify platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\IMDBReview.apk` and it is showing this as output

`jarsigner: java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA-256 signature file digest for assets/www/svg/logo-reddit.svg`

and to resolve that I have delete that file by extracting the .apk as per this post `https://k2xl.com/wordpress/you-uploaded-an-apk-with-invalid-or-missing-signing-information-for-some-of-its-files-google-play-adobe-air-error/`

So, now there is no file available which was causing issue but still it is showing me same error and above verify command also showing me same error

Here is the URL of visual studio where error is showing - `prnt.sc/p5phqn`

And here is the URL of folder where no such file exist - `prnt.sc/p5pipl`

You can see URLs in my first comment as well

Comment: Here is the URL of visual studio where error is showing - https://prnt.sc/p5phqn

And here is the URL of folder where no such file exist - https://prnt.sc/p5pipl

Comment: try to remove platform and add it again then try it might work

Comment: @user9088454 I already did it 2 times but no luck. Same error both of the times.

Comment: Maybe this will not resolve your issue but you can't upload a debug version of the app to the store. Even if you manage to sign it you will nevere be able to upload it

Comment: @MauroSemproni It is not a debug version man. I have converted it to signed apk you can see the command there. It is used for sign the app. Just name is app-debug.apk which was generated by command via command line

Comment: if you run `ionic cordova build [platform]` you will get a debug version named app-debug.apk. You have to run `ionic cordova build [platform] --release` to obtain a prod version named app-release.apk. A debug version is stil a debug version even if you sign it

Comment: @MauroSemproni I will try this today. I hope this will help and resolve the issue.

Comment: @MauroSemproni It helped. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MauroSemproni  Please add your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running

```
    ionic cordova build android
```

you obtain a file named **app-debug.apk**. As the name suggest this version is for debug only and can't be uploaded to the store. Even if you sign it Play Store will not allow you to upload it, so struggling with those errors is a waste of time, you need a release version first.
To obtain such version you have to run

```
    ionic cordova build android --release
```

the output of this command will be a file named **app-release.apk**. Try to sign that one